# Cancellationtoken in OnAuthorizationAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following code:

```
public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRolesAttribute() : base(typeof(AuthorizeRolesFilter))
    {

    }

    public class AuthorizeRolesFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public virtual async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to use Cancellation token, so I'm trying to override it like this:

```
public async override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context, CancellationToken ct)
{
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> No suitable method found to override

Comment: You can't change a method's signature when you override it.

Comment: Have you checked if HttpContext is available on the `context` parameter? It has a RequestAborted cancellation token you could potentially use.

Answer (score 6):

Just acquire your `CancellationToken` from the [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.requestaborted?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

```
public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var cancellationToken = context.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
    ...
}
```